# In Spark 2.2, is there a difference between calling .repartition(#) and setting default partition values?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In some of the Spark jobs we run at work, I've taken to setting:

```
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=400
```

in the start scripts. It made the jobs pretty nice and stable after sometimes hitting OOM errors.

But is there a difference between setting this value and manually calling

```
df.repartition(400)
```

somewhere in the code? If my goal is to trade shuffle speed for having the data evenly distributed, I'd prefer the latter in my case. If we can rely on setting the --conf to take care of this, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is different `--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=400` configuration says how many files should be created once shuffle is occur in your application, it can be due to join, groupBy, distinct. Where `df.repartition(400)` says you forcing dataframe to shuffle its data and create 400 partitions.